# Credit Card Payment(master Card and Visa) in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

Do we have any package for Credit Card Payment in Paypal in Laravel 5.2.37?

I am already following this to link my app with Paypal : http://learninglaravel.net/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4-laravel-5 and now want to check any package for Credit Card(Master Card/Visa)

Comment: https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment
https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal

Comment: I am already following this to link my app with Paypal : http://learninglaravel.net/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4-laravel-5 and now want to check any package for Credit Card(Master Card/Visa)

Comment: @Pankaj even i'm following the same link and want to integrate credit/debit card.so please help me 1) which package you end up using.2)And is it working in india

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## PayPal

These packages are for PayPal only and can be used to process credit cards.

- [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)

  - [PayPal Developer REST API Samples](https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/)
  - [PHPBuilder - Working with the PayPal API](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/shopping-carts/working-with-the-paypal-api.html)
  - [17 Educations - Paypal integration in laravel](http://www.17educations.com/laravel/paypal-integration-in-laravel/)
- [laravel-paypalpayment](https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment)
- [laravel-paypal](https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal)

## Multiple Services

These packages are for more than one payment processor and include PayPal. They can be used to process credit cards.

- [Omnipay for Laravel 5 & Lumen](https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay)

  - [Omnipay Simple Example](http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/simple-example/)
- [Payum](https://github.com/Payum/PayumLaravelPackage)
- [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing) (official Laravel package; supports PayPal via Braintree; meant for subscriptions / recurring billing plans)

  - [EnvatoTuts - Process Payments With Stripe and Laravel Cashier](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/process-payments-with-stripe-and-laravel-cashier)
  - [ItSolutionStuff - Laravel 5 Stripe example using Laravel Cashier from Scratch](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-stripe-example-using-laravel-cashier-from-scratchexample.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Omnipay

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay

It supports paypal and tens of other major payment providers, with a simple unique interface for all of them

Install & use instructions are on the github project page, package are available for composer